# How to fix shell injection exploits in PHP?

Tags: php, shell, code-injection, exploit

We have someone exploiting our website and giving themselves funds to make purchases without actually depositing any money. When running a Vega scanner to look for vulnerabilities, it seems almost all of our pages have shell injection exploits open.

The program says the following 2 requests (basically on any page because this PHP code is in the header.php) are leaving us vulnerable.

```
GET /web-hosting.php?cid=1`true`
GET /web-hosting.php?cid=1"`true`"
GET /style.css?1=null`true`
GET /style.css?1=null"`true`"
```

When Looking at the header.php code, I noticed the linked CSS files have "?1" after them. I did not code this site so I am not sure if they were always been present but there is no good reason for this parameter being placed there is there? It seems like it just opens us up to exploits.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css?1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-custom.css?1" />
```

*EDIT*

Here is the code that is used in the header that takes cid.php as a parameter.

```
<?php
// Enter WHMCS Folder location  eg "whmcs"
$location = "customers";


require("".$location."/dbconnect.php");
if (isset($_REQUEST['cid'])) $_SESSION['currency'] = $_REQUEST['cid'];

?>
```

I am not overly familiar with shell injections, however I don't really get how this makes any sense. I tried entering the URL in the browser but it just loaded the page. What do these actually do and how can they be fixed?

Comment: I think you want this: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: You should hire a professional, immediately.

Comment: The exploits seem to be limited to the a certain included script which takes cid as a parameter so I can fix that myself by changing it to use mysqli I believe. I am more just curious about the ?1 which I think can be fixed just by removing that from the actual link lines but wasn't sure.

Comment: shell injection is not sql injection. As it stands we cannot provide any sort of diagnostic without reading the code.

Comment: I am not sure what code to provide, I have edited the original post to show the PHP code in the header which takes the CID param.

Comment: Please check that register_globals is turned off. `phpinfo()`. Further reading: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals If this ini variable is on, you are in deep trouble indeed

Comment: Are you running the most recent version of WHMCS? There is an [open bug bounty program on Bugcrowd](https://bugcrowd.com/whmcs), which may have resulted in the discovery of some security flaws, which may not have been fixed yet or even reported to the vendor. But nonetheless, you should hire a professional that can track down the attack path.

Comment: Sebas: We are using PHP 5.4.33 where it appears from that link Register Globals has been removed entirely.
Gumbo: We do indeed have the latest version of WHMCS. I am not sure what that is on Bugcrowd but I believe all known exploits have been fixed as of the latest version.

Comment: What is `$_SESSION["currency"]`? Is it possible that the value of this variable is being used in a vulnerable fashion?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to filter the input (which you should always do anyway).  The MySQL Real Escape String below is soon to be deprecated code but might work for now.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

```
<?php
//...
if (isset($_REQUEST['cid']))
  $_SESSION['currency'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['cid']);

?>
```

You may want to filter the cid variable further by making sure it isn't too long, doesn't have special characters, matches a pattern, etc.